# Unity test setup forcibly excludes all the code I would want to test from the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add unit tests to a Unity project.  I'm using the Unity TestRunner window, adding an Edit Mode Test Assembly Folder, and adding a test C# script to it.  The file is generated fine.

However, I can't actually test any of the main project's code because the test project can't see it.  The `Tests.csproj` that Unity is setting up doesn't include any of the `.cs` files from the main directory tree; all it includes is, for some reason, a `.txt` file.  I can change this situation temporarily by copying over the XML from the main project's `.csproj` file into `Tests.csproj`, but Unity rewrites `Tests.csproj` to put it back how it had it the next time it pays attention.

The Unity documentation doesn't hint at anything like this needing to be addressed.  The MSVS documentation says I need to add a Reference to the project, but the `Tests > References` context menu under Unity doesn't have the `Add Reference` option it talks about.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have to follow the [*assembly definition*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) paradigm they rolled out recently.

Example:

- in Assets, create a **Graphics** folder
- add some classes to it
- add an *Assembly Definition*
- in Assets, create a **TestsEditMode** folder using Test Runner window
- add some tests to it still with Test Runner window
- add an *Assembly Definition* then reference **Graphics** in it

You end up with the following:

[image]

[The documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html) is confusing, as usual ...

Basically this turns out to be opt-in, which is rather good in the end.